# How can I Use Win32 and GDI calls to write text characters to a bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi

I'm working on a c# (.NET Framework) program that uses SharpGL.  That library has methods to draw text to the OpenGL context using the wglUseFontBitmaps call from Win32; however, that method uses display lists that were **deprecated** in v3.0.  I'd therefore like to find a way to use VBOs and VAOs to draw texts.  However, the wglUseFontBitmaps method produces reasonably legible text even at font sizes of 10 or 12 (which I need).

I have tried to match that outcome using several approaches including .NET's GlyphTypeface.GetGlyphOutlines and SharpFont (which wraps FreeType).  With both of those I tried rendering larger size fonts (without antialiasing) and letting OpenGL scale them to smaller sizes.  I still can't get reliably good looking results that match wglUseFontBitmaps.

So, My current attempt is to use the Win32 GDI APIs to write the text, assuming it might produce similar results to wglUseFontBitmaps; however, I can't get the first step to work -- just writing a character into a bitmap.

Below I'm posting an entire c# program file.  It can be complied as a .NET Framework Console application, but you must add a reference to System.Drawing and you must turn on "Allow unsafe code" in the Project's preferences under the Build tab.

Currently, it creates very odd bitmap files (and, by the way, it will write the test file called "TMP.BMP" into your desktop folder).

Here's the code -- a bit long but includes all you need to run the test:

```c#
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CharToBitmapConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tester = new CharToBitmapTester();
            tester.RunTests();
        }

        // Calls the TestWithCharacter method a few times for testing
        public class CharToBitmapTester
        {
            public void RunTests()
            {
                var fontFamilyName = "Calibri";
                var fontHeight = 14;

                TestWithCharacter((int)'%', fontFamilyName, fontHeight);
                TestWithCharacter((int)'#', fontFamilyName, fontHeight);
                TestWithCharacter((int)'X', fontFamilyName, fontHeight);
                TestWithCharacter((int)'H', fontFamilyName, fontHeight);
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Attempts to do every step needed to write a characte (corersponding to the given
            /// unicode index) into a bitmap using the given font family name and font height.
            /// The test returns true if any bits were written to memory as a result of the
            /// attempt. The test also writes a bitmap file (TMP.BMP) to the Users's desktop.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="unicodeIndex"></param>
            /// <param name="fontFamilyName"></param>
            /// <param name="fontHeight"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public bool TestWithCharacter(int unicodeIndex, string fontFamilyName, int fontHeight)
            {
                //var hDC = gl.RenderContextProvider.DeviceContextHandle;
                //  Get the desktop DC.
                IntPtr desktopDC = WinGdi32.GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
                //  Create our DC as a compatible DC for the desktop.
                var hDC = WinGdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(desktopDC);

                // Create the font handle (IntPtr) for the WinGDI font object
                var hFont = WinGdi32.CreateFont(fontHeight, 0, 0, 0, WinGdi32.FW_DONTCARE, 0, 0, 0, WinGdi32.DEFAULT_CHARSET,
                    WinGdi32.OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS, WinGdi32.CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, WinGdi32.CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, WinGdi32.VARIABLE_PITCH, fontFamilyName);

                // Select the font object into the Device Context
                // GDI actions will use hFont as the current font object
                WinGdi32.SelectObject(hDC, hFont);

                // Get the true widths for the glyph placement of all the characters
                var charWidthInfoArray = new WinGdi32.ABCFLOAT[256];
                WinGdi32.GetCharABCWidthsFloat(hDC, 0, 255, charWidthInfoArray);

                char character = (char)unicodeIndex;
                string characterAsString = character.ToString();

                var characterWidthInfo = charWidthInfoArray[unicodeIndex];
                var characterFullWidth = characterWidthInfo.abcfA + characterWidthInfo.abcfB + characterWidthInfo.abcfC;

                var glyphUnitWidth = (int)Math.Ceiling(characterWidthInfo.abcfB);
                var glyphUnitHeight = (int)fontHeight;


                //*************************************************************************************
                //  Create a DIBSection
                // 
                // Start with the BITMAPINFO
                var bitCount = 24;// 32;
                var info = new WinGdi32.BITMAPINFO();
                //  Set the data.
                info.biSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
                info.biBitCount = (short)bitCount;
                info.biPlanes = 1;
                info.biWidth = glyphUnitWidth;
                info.biHeight = glyphUnitHeight;

                IntPtr bits;
                //  Create the bitmap.
                var hBitmap = WinGdi32.CreateDIBSection(hDC, ref info, WinGdi32.DIB_RGB_COLORS, out bits, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
                WinGdi32.SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);

                //  Set the pixel format.
                var pixelFormat = new WinGdi32.PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR();
                pixelFormat.Init();
                pixelFormat.nVersion = 1;
                pixelFormat.dwFlags = (WinGdi32.PFD_DRAW_TO_BITMAP | WinGdi32.PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | WinGdi32.PFD_SUPPORT_GDI);
                pixelFormat.iPixelType = WinGdi32.PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
                pixelFormat.cColorBits = (byte)bitCount;
                pixelFormat.cDepthBits = (byte)bitCount;
                pixelFormat.iLayerType = WinGdi32.PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

                //  Try to match a pixel format and note failure if we get an error
                int iPixelformat;
                if ((iPixelformat = WinGdi32.ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, pixelFormat)) == 0)
                    return false;

                //  Sets pixel format and test for errors
                if (WinGdi32.SetPixelFormat(hDC, iPixelformat, pixelFormat) == 0)
                {
                    //  Falure -- clear error and retur nfalse
                    int _ = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    return false;
                }

                //  Done Creating a DIBSection
                //  If I understand correctly, the hDC now has the DIBSction as the current object and
                //  calls related to drawing should go to it (and, I belive, fill our "bits" buffer)
                //*************************************************************************************


                // Set a location to output the text -- not really sure what to use here but going with 0, 0
                int x = 0;
                int y = 9;
                // Could play around with foreground and background colors...
                //var prevFgColorRef = WinGdi32.SetTextColor(hDC, ColorTranslator.ToWin32(System.Drawing.Color.White));
                //var prevBkColorRef = WinGdi32.SetBkColor(hDC, ColorTranslator.ToWin32(System.Drawing.Color.Black));
                // NOTE: we've already set hFont as the current font and hBitmap as the current bitmap...

                // Output the text -- this should go to the current bitmap and fill the bits buffer, right?
                var textOutWorked = WinGdi32.TextOut(hDC, x, y, characterAsString.ToString(), 1);

                if (textOutWorked)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TextOut finished without complaint");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TextOut says it did NOT work");
                    return false;
                }

                var dibSectionSize = glyphUnitWidth * glyphUnitHeight * bitCount;
                var testArray = new byte[dibSectionSize];
                Marshal.Copy(bits, testArray, 0, dibSectionSize);

                var bitsWithData = 0;
                foreach (var b in testArray)
                {
                    if (b != 0)
                    {
                        bitsWithData++;
                    }
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(bitsWithData > 0 ? 
                    $"Test Wrote something to the bits! Font {fontFamilyName};  Character: {characterAsString}!" :
                    $"Test did NOT write to the bits! Font {fontFamilyName};  Character: {characterAsString}!");

                var stride = bitCount * glyphUnitWidth;
                using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(glyphUnitWidth, glyphUnitHeight, stride, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, bits))
                {
                    bitmap.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "TMP.BMP"));
                }

                return bitsWithData > 0;
            }

        }



        public static class WinGdi32
        {
            public const string Gdi32 = "gdi32.dll";
            public const string User32 = "user32.dll";

            /// <summary>
            /// The TextOut function writes a character string at the specified location, using the currently selected font, background color, and text color
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="hDC">A handle to the device context.</param>
            /// <param name="x">The x-coordinate, in logical coordinates, of the reference point that the system uses to align the string.</param>
            /// <param name="y">The y-coordinate, in logical coordinates, of the reference point that the system uses to align the string.</param>
            /// <param name="str">The string to be drawn. The string does not need to be zero-terminated, because cchString specifies the length of the string.</param>
            /// <param name="c">The length of the string in characters.</param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            [DllImport(Gdi32, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern bool TextOut(IntPtr hDC, int x, int y, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str, int c);


            /// <summary>
            /// The GetCharABCWidthsFloat function retrieves the widths, in logical units, of consecutive characters in a specified range from the current font.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="hDC">Handle to the device context.</param>
            /// <param name="iFirstChar">Specifies the code point of the first character in the group of consecutive characters where the ABC widths are seeked.</param>
            /// <param name="iLastChar">Specifies the code point of the last character in the group of consecutive characters where the ABC widths are seeked. This range is inclusive. An error is returned if the specified last character precedes the specified first character</param>
            /// <param name="ABCF">An array of ABCFLOAT structures that receives the character widths, in logical units</param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            [DllImport(Gdi32, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern bool GetCharABCWidthsFloat(IntPtr hDC, uint iFirstChar, uint iLastChar, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ABCFLOAT[] ABCF);


            [DllImport(Gdi32, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr SetTextColor(IntPtr hDC, int crColor);
            [DllImport(Gdi32, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr SetBkColor(IntPtr hDC, int crColor);

            [DllImport(Gdi32, SetLastError = true)]
            public unsafe static extern int ChoosePixelFormat(IntPtr hDC, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR ppfd);

            [DllImport(Gdi32, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateDIBSection(IntPtr hdc, [In] ref BITMAPINFO pbmi, uint pila, out IntPtr ppvBits, IntPtr hSection, uint dwOffset);

            [DllImport(Gdi32, SetLastError = true)]
            public unsafe static extern int SetPixelFormat(IntPtr hDC, int iPixelFormat, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR ppfd);


            [DllImport(User32, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

            [DllImport(Gdi32, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);

            [DllImport(Gdi32, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateFont(int nHeight, int nWidth, int nEscapement,
                int nOrientation, uint fnWeight, uint fdwItalic, uint fdwUnderline, uint fdwStrikeOut,
                uint fdwCharSet, uint fdwOutputPrecision, uint fdwClipPrecision, uint fdwQuality,
                uint fdwPitchAndFamily, string lpszFace);

            [DllImport(Gdi32, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hgdiobj);







            /// <summary>
            /// The SIZE structure specifies the width and height of a rectangle.
            /// </summary>
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public class SIZE
            {
                /// <summary>
                /// Specifies the rectangle's width. The units depend on which function uses this.
                /// </summary>
                public long cx;
                /// <summary>
                /// Specifies the rectangle's height. The units depend on which function uses this.
                /// </summary>
                public long cy;
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// The ABCFLOAT structure contains the A, B, and C widths of a font character.
            /// </summary>
            public struct ABCFLOAT
            {
                /// <summary>
                /// The A spacing of the character.  The A spacing is the distance to add to the current position before drawing the character glyph.
                /// </summary>
                public float abcfA;
                /// <summary>
                /// The B spacing of the character.  The B spacing is the width of the drawn portion of the character glyph.
                /// </summary>
                public float abcfB;
                /// <summary>
                /// The C spacing of the character.  The C spacing is the distance to add to the current position to provide white space to the right of the character glyph.
                /// </summary>
                public float abcfC;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct BITMAPINFO
            {
                public Int32 biSize;
                public Int32 biWidth;
                public Int32 biHeight;
                public Int16 biPlanes;
                public Int16 biBitCount;
                public Int32 biCompression;
                public Int32 biSizeImage;
                public Int32 biXPelsPerMeter;
                public Int32 biYPelsPerMeter;
                public Int32 biClrUsed;
                public Int32 biClrImportant;

                public void Init()
                {
                    biSize = Marshal.SizeOf(this);
                }
            }


            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
            public class PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR
            {
                [FieldOffset(0)]
                public UInt16 nSize;
                [FieldOffset(2)]
                public UInt16 nVersion;
                [FieldOffset(4)]
                public UInt32 dwFlags;
                [FieldOffset(8)]
                public Byte iPixelType;
                [FieldOffset(9)]
                public Byte cColorBits;
                [FieldOffset(10)]
                public Byte cRedBits;
                [FieldOffset(11)]
                public Byte cRedShift;
                [FieldOffset(12)]
                public Byte cGreenBits;
                [FieldOffset(13)]
                public Byte cGreenShift;
                [FieldOffset(14)]
                public Byte cBlueBits;
                [FieldOffset(15)]
                public Byte cBlueShift;
                [FieldOffset(16)]
                public Byte cAlphaBits;
                [FieldOffset(17)]
                public Byte cAlphaShift;
                [FieldOffset(18)]
                public Byte cAccumBits;
                [FieldOffset(19)]
                public Byte cAccumRedBits;
                [FieldOffset(20)]
                public Byte cAccumGreenBits;
                [FieldOffset(21)]
                public Byte cAccumBlueBits;
                [FieldOffset(22)]
                public Byte cAccumAlphaBits;
                [FieldOffset(23)]
                public Byte cDepthBits;
                [FieldOffset(24)]
                public Byte cStencilBits;
                [FieldOffset(25)]
                public Byte cAuxBuffers;
                [FieldOffset(26)]
                public SByte iLayerType;
                [FieldOffset(27)]
                public Byte bReserved;
                [FieldOffset(28)]
                public UInt32 dwLayerMask;
                [FieldOffset(32)]
                public UInt32 dwVisibleMask;
                [FieldOffset(36)]
                public UInt32 dwDamageMask;

                public void Init()
                {
                    nSize = (ushort)Marshal.SizeOf(this);
                }
            }

            public const uint FW_DONTCARE = 0;

            public const uint ANSI_CHARSET = 0;
            public const uint DEFAULT_CHARSET = 1;
            public const uint SYMBOL_CHARSET = 2;

            public const uint OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS = 8;
            public const uint CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS = 0;

            public const uint CLEARTYPE_QUALITY = 5;

            public const uint FIXED_PITCH = 1;
            public const uint VARIABLE_PITCH = 2;

            public const uint DIB_RGB_COLORS = 0;

            public const uint PFD_DRAW_TO_BITMAP = 8;

            public const uint PFD_SUPPORT_GDI = 16;
            public const uint PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL = 32;

            public const byte PFD_TYPE_RGBA = 0;

            public const sbyte PFD_MAIN_PLANE = 0;

        }

    }
}
```

If anyone can tell me how to get the code to actually write individual characters to a bitmap, I should be able to take it from there and use it in my OpenGL project.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just use GDI+ with the official `Bitmap` and `Graphics` classes?

Comment: Why would you want to resize bitmap text? Just make an atlas for each size if you need more than one, it's not like it's going to cause you any real trouble. Then you can use proper anti-aliased text (though doing full fledged sub-pixel rendering ala ClearType is really tricky if you want to render in 3D). And like Charlieface said, there's little point of using GDI when you have GDI+ available without dealing with manual native interop. It would be really helpful if you showed the kind of trouble you're having (e.g. screenshots for comparison of what you get vs. what you want).

Comment: @Luaan, Thanks for the comment.  I usually do generate a different bitmap for each font family and size; however, I found that with `GetGlyphOutlines` and SharpFont, the smaller sizes had poor quality, so I TRIED the method of making them bigger and letting OpenGL resize them (which was only moderately better and only in some cases).  I used GDI because I was more familiar with its calls (SharpGL uses them) but I'll look into GDI+.  I'll consider posting some images, but while they could highlight my overall issue, the code I posted generates almost empty bitmaps, which is my current problem.

Comment: @FTLPhysicsGuy You should try with bigger bitmaps first; I wouldn't be surprised if there were some offsets etc. that you're not expecting (normally the text size functions account for things like accents, even if they aren't there - otherwise accented characters will not fit properly).

Answer (score 1):

Just to show, this would be a sample using GDI+:

```
var text = "Hello world!";
var font = new Font("Calibri", 8);
var bitmap = new Bitmap(200, 100);
var targetRectangle = new RectangleF(0, 0, 200, 120);

var sf = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericDefault);
sf.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(
      Enumerable.Range(0, text.Length)
      .Select(i => new CharacterRange(i, 1)).ToArray());

using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    gr.Clear(Color.Black);

    gr.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.White, targetRectangle, sf);

    var ranges = gr.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, targetRectangle, sf);   
    gr.DrawRectangles(Pens.Red, ranges.Select(i => i.GetBounds(gr)).ToArray());
}

bitmap.Dump();
```

This produces a bitmap containing the text "Hello world!" along with the area of each of the characters (though those are not actually the *bounds* of the characters - careful with accents). This allows you to create an atlas of characters for rendering easily (you'd want more spacing between the characters to deal with the overlap, of course).

This produces legible text down to about 6 emsize (8 is much better, though), but that does require sub-pixel rendering, which means this is only suitable when you don't need to scale the font (e.g. for UI). There's many ways to tweak this - the defaults are a compromise between rendering speed and quality. For example, using `gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;` will give you much sharper and nicer text (especially for such a tiny font size in a font not optimised for small size or minimal aliasing) by aligning the characters better (at the cost of being less "pixel perfect"). By the time you get to emsize around 12, the artefacts tend to be mostly invisible even with a bit of scaling (provided you configured ClearType properly). Of course, the results depend on the geometry of the pixels of your display - they're not portable. Both GDI and GDI+ are primarily meant to be used for presentation, not to produce device independent graphics. You'd probably want to use specialised software for that.

You can also remove all hinting using `gr.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;`. This will tend to produce poor text rendering with modern fonts; it really needs a font optimized for rendering without sub-pixels. The main advantage is that it will look the same regardless of your hardware - but it tends to look very bad.

Comment: Looks promising, but I need help to fit it into my current construct.  I'm using System.Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface to know the rectangle that exactly encompasses the pixels in each glyph in an atlas.  Using GDI+, how do I know the extent of the non-blank pixels in each glyph and how do I know how much to shift left/down when placing it in a string?  For example, a 16pt "!" character is 2 pixels wide, but `DrawString` adds pixels on either side to make it look "crisp".  If the pixel sizes don't match GlyphTypeface, then neither will baseline position, bearing, or advance values.  Can you help?

Comment: @FTLPhysicsGuy That's what you get when you move the vector font onto a raster, unfortunately. Depending on the position of the !, it will look very different. !i! has two different `!`'s. GDI+ _is_ meant for showing stuff on the screen right now. Drawing text is a rather complex problem. On DirectX, you have DirectWrite to handle perfect realtime text rendering. You will _never_ get perfect text rendering from a vector font reduced to a bitmap - don't compare to text you get from e.g. DrawString, compare to other rendering that uses bitmap fonts. It's best to use fonts designed for that.

Comment: @FTLPhysicsGuy I don't think there's any (public) function in GDI+ that will help you with the kerning and sub-pixel rendering, unfortunately. It's all done internally, and it's not portable. Using it with GlyphTypeface can give reasonably good results if you're careful, but it's not going to work 100%. QuickFont is decent (and easy to use) text library to use with OpenGL, but it just doesn't compare in quality to DirectDraw. When I was still dealing with text in games, I always chose to do the bitmap fonts manually (or at least retouching the rasterization).

Comment: @FTLPhysicsGuy For UI text, I prefer to just render entire pieces of text, rather than rendering character by character, and caching the results as necessary. It's not the fastest approach, but it was never a bottleneck for me (and I've always done games that are heavy on UI and text). This way you can afford to do the best text rendering there is, which is especially useful when dealing with modern fonts and small font sizes. It's very easy to work with, gives you full support for all sorts of languages, shifts all of the burden to the OS (or a 3rd party library)...

Comment: @FTLPhysicsGuy Of course, you can also just crop the characters if you really want to - that will give you a decent way to combine the rendering using `DrawString` (make sure to play around with the rendering options to get good results) and getting the kerning information from GlyphTypeface (or SharpFont). It's not going to be perfect, and it will only really work reasonably well for English text, but it's also quite simple to do, with well-scaling text.

Comment: Just want to thank everyone for the comments.  About my project: think of it as a screen showing the results of aircraft radar tracks over time.  There can be lots of tracks and each track can have many points.  The "current" point of each track can have several labels, and so it is possible to have plenty of text to render on screen (though I do hide them if you zoom out far enough).  As noted in the original post, I currently use wglUseFontBitmaps, which gives acceptable results but uses deprecated display lists.  Still trying to make FreeType take its place, but I like having other options.

Comment: @FTLPhysicsGuy Honestly, I wouldn't be too worried about display lists being deprecated. They're deprecated in the Core set, which is used by... noone, give or take. You aren't using it, otherwise your code wouldn't work (it's been removed entirely from Core for a long time). As for the cost of rendering the fonts using GDI+ as needed, it's unlikely to be a problem unless the texts change very often (in my sample, I can easily render 20k unique strings per second). Don't forget that most of the text you see on your screen is already rendered by GDI in much the same manner.